# SweetAlert não Retorna Falso

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Eu fiz alguns inputs no formato text e depois criei uma funcao em javascript para fazer a verificação de campos vazios dos mesmos, mas quando eu aperto o botão próximo ele mostra o erro(a caixinha do sweetalert normal descrevendo o erro como esperado), mas depois ele avança para a próxima pagina normal ao enves de dar false, segue o codigo:

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="endereco-aluno">Endereço: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco-aluno">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="bairro-aluno">Bairro: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro-aluno">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

esse é o html normal o button que fiz para verificar os campos foram esse:

```
                    <button class="forward" id="botaoProximo2" style="margin-top: 15px; float: right;"
                        onclick="SOLICITAR_ESTAGIO.verificaCamposDadosEstudante()">Próximo</button>
```

E o javaScript foi esse:

```
    verificaCamposDadosEstudante: function () {

        var endereco_aluno = $("#endereco-aluno").val();
        var bairro_aluno = $("#bairro-aluno").val();

        if (endereco_aluno == '') {
            swal("Oops", "Para avançar você precisar informar o Endereço.", "error");
            return false;
        } else if (bairro_aluno == '') {
            swal("Oops", "Para avançar você precisar informar a Bairro.", "error");
            return false;
        } 
    },
```

os campos com READONLY já são preenchidos automaticamente e não é necessário verificação

Comment: Seu botão está dentro de um form?

Comment: não, está tudo dentro de uma section

Comment: Então você avança a pagina com outro evento ou dentro do `verificaCamposDadosEstudante`?

Comment: onclick="SOLICITAR_ESTAGIO.verificaCamposDadosEstudante()", neste evento, eu quero saber se o problema é pelo button class="forward" e por isso ele talvez nao ta retornando false

Comment: no onclick eu faço as verificaçoes dos campos vazios e se estiver emite o sweetalert e consequentemente o false, eu vou ter que colocar a class do button foward dentro desse javascript ? eu nao to entendendo o que ta acontecendo

Comment: Então você usa algum plugin para controlar essa pagina? Porque parece que tem algum evento nesse mesmo botão que executa junto com a sua função de validação

Comment: pra mim o que eu acho que ta acontecendo é o button foward cagando tudo

Comment: nao tem problema nenhum na parte que vc informou, coloquei uma resposta com um exemplo funcional.

Comment: posta o codigo relacionado ao SOLICITAR_ESTAGIO

Comment: Não tem como o javascript tem mais de 1300 linhas e aqui ele nao permite

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar no seu evento o `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)), ele interrompe todos os outros eventos que iriam executar junto com o botão. Você precisa passar o objeto do evento com `onclick="SOLICITAR_ESTAGIO.verificaCamposDadosEstudante(event)"`

```js
$('.forward').on('click', function() { alert('Proxima Pagina') })

const SOLICITAR_ESTAGIO = {
     verificaCamposDadosEstudante: function (e) {

        var endereco_aluno = '';
        var bairro_aluno = '';

        if (endereco_aluno == '') {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            swal("Oops", "Para avançar você precisar informar o Endereço.", "error");
            return false;
        } else if (bairro_aluno == '') {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            swal("Oops", "Para avançar você precisar informar a Bairro.", "error");
            return false;
        } 
    },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button onclick="SOLICITAR_ESTAGIO.verificaCamposDadosEstudante(event)" class="forward" id="botaoProximo2" style="margin-top: 15px; float: right;" >Próximo</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu sweetalert nao tem nenhum problema.

```js
function verificaCamposDadosEstudante () {

        var endereco_aluno = $("#endereco-aluno").val();
        var bairro_aluno = $("#bairro-aluno").val();

        if (endereco_aluno == '') {
            swal("Oops", "Para avançar você precisar informar o Endereço.", "error");
            return false;
        } else if (bairro_aluno == '') {
            swal("Oops", "Para avançar você precisar informar a Bairro.", "error");
            return false;
        } 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="endereco-aluno">Endereço: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco-aluno">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="bairro-aluno">Bairro: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro-aluno">
                        </div>
                    </div>

<button class="forward" id="botaoProximo2" style="margin-top: 15px; float: right;"
                        onclick="verificaCamposDadosEstudante()">Próximo</button>
```

Comment: o problema é que se voce criar uma outra pagina e deixar o botao em foward em caso de campo vazio o seewtalert nao retorna true, eu acho que ele esta dando conflito com o foward...

Comment: @ArthurFelipe nao tem conflito nenhum provavelmente vc fez algum construtor que ta executando algo que nao deveria. E vc precisa colocar o return true no codigo tambem logo apos o sweetalert